# Взаимодействие с БД(реляционной) в коммерческом проекте

Tags: sql, база-данных

Разрабатывается коммерческий проект с использованием реляционной БД. Допустим клиент-серверное приложение. Сервер взаимодействует с БД.

Вопрос: где хранить, хранятся sql инструкции, которые использует сервер для взаимодействия с БД. Это отдельный файл, хранящий их и который загружается после запуска сервера? Если это файл, то какую он имеет структуру и формат?

Comment: какой язык программирования сервера?

Comment: @BogdanK, язык Java

Comment: У вас тут довольно много вопросов в одном. Про терминологию в идеале нужно читать документацию, а если спрашивать здесь — то отдельным вопросом, может быть даже про каждый термин отдельно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, здесь 2 вопроса: 1- что, когда использовать(Причем хотелось бы услышать ответы-мнение разработчиков с опытом) 2 - как организовывается взаимодействие с бд в реальных коммерческих проектах

Comment: @NickVolynkin, согласен 2 вопроса не связаны, изменил

Comment: (1) Назначение каждой из перечисленных вами вещей прямо вытекает из определения каждой из них, непонятно, какие пояснения вам нужны. (2) Где угодно. Лишь бы сервер имел возможность слать базе указания выполнять нужные ему команды. Можно вшивать в код сервера, можно держать в отдельных файлах, можно держать в отдельных файлах и макросами вшивать в код при компиляции. Никаких особых типов файлов для этого нет. используется то, что способна воспринимать технология, на которой сделан сервер.

Comment: @bsuart2017 ага, вот теперь хорошо, плюс от меня )

Comment: @D-side, Я понимаю, что можно и в файле и в самом коде. Спрошу так: как делает вы?

Comment: @bsuart2017 всеми перечисленными способами, предпочтительно по одному на проект. Что именно вы хотите узнать?

Comment: @D-side, я хочу конкретно узнать, как делают профессионалы взаимодействие с бд, прописывают в самом коде: 'String StatemenRequestnSql = new String("INSERT INTO pharamacy.request ( request, phone_number) VALUES ('"+newRequest.getNameRequestTablet() +"', '"+newRequest.getNumber()+"')");
 db.ExecuteStatement(StatemenRequestnSql);' Либо выносят сами sql-конструкции в файл и при запуске приложение их считывает и уже работает с ними.

Comment: @bsuart2017 на этот вопрос я вам ответил: по-разному, в зависимости от ситуации и требований. Вы хотите описание "когда и где"?

Comment: @D-side, хотелось бы, если не трудно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мы говорим о Java, то инструкции "хранятся" внутри сервера в виде java-кода. Там могут быть как SQL-запросы, так и код, который использует фреймворк для работы с БД. Примером такого фреймворка может служить [HibernateORM](http://hibernate.org/orm/).